# TypeError: string indices must be integers when reading data from json

Tags: python, json

I am trying to pull the title out of my `.json` file. Ended up with an error. Wondering if any of you could assist me and point out what I am doing wrong.

I have the problem code down below with the error code.

```
title = ('0')
for eq_data in all_eq_data:
    title = (eq_data['metadata']['title'])
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\2\Desktop\python_work\Chapter 16 - 20\Chapter 16\16.7 Automated Title.py", line 29, in <module>
    title = (eq_data['metadata']['title'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
[Finished in 661ms]
```

---

Below is a snippet of the data I am trying to pull and how it looks like

---

```
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "metadata": {
        "generated": 1550361461000,
        "url": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_day.geojson",
        "title": "USGS Magnitude 1.0+ Earthquakes, Past Day",
        "status": 200,
        "api": "1.7.0",
        "count": 158
```

---

People are getting confused. Ill post the rest of the code below

---

```
import json

from plotly.graph_objs import Scattergeo, Layout
from plotly import offline

# Explore the structure of the data.
filename = 'data/eq_data_30_day_m1.json'
with open(filename) as f:
    all_eq_data = json.load(f)


all_eq_dicts = all_eq_data['features']

mags, lons, lats, hover_texts = [], [], [], []
for eq_dict in all_eq_dicts:
    mags.append(eq_dict['properties']['mag'])
    lons.append(eq_dict['geometry']['coordinates'][0])
    lats.append(eq_dict['geometry']['coordinates'][1])
    hover_texts.append(eq_dict['properties']['title'])


#all_eq_info = all_eq_data

title = ('0')
for eq_data in all_eq_data:
    title = (eq_data['metadata']['title'])

# Map the earthquake.
data = [{
    'type': 'scattergeo',
    'lon': lons,
    'lat': lats,
    'text': hover_texts,
    'marker': {
        'size': [3*mag for mag in mags],
        'color': mags,
        'colorscale': 'Viridis',
        'reversescale': True,
        'colorbar': {'title': 'Magnitude'},
    }
}]
my_layout = Layout(title=title)

fig = {'data': data, 'layout': my_layout}
offline.plot(fig, filename='auto_global_earthquakes.html')
```

Comment: 1. That is not valid json. 2. What is `eq_data`? Presumably, `eq_data` or `eq_data['metadata']` is a string. Please provide a [mre] that we can run and will reproduce your problem

Comment: It's hard to tell without all of your source data, but either the entire json or one of it's values is of type `string` and not `dict`, make sure you are properly parsing the JSON into a python `dict`

Comment: cant make a minimal reproducible example since I cant share a `.json` file over the web to you as easily as I can type. Want me to post the data? That I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are accessing the raw JSON string, you have to parse the string into an object before you can reference it. In Python that means using the `json` module. The easiest way of doing this is using `json.loads()`.

**Example:**

```py
import json

json_string = '{"title": "some title", "data": "some data"}'

#should return a dictionary with "some title" as "title" and "some data" as "data"
data = json.loads(json_string)
```